# Finding $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{z^2+z^{-2}}{(z^*-r_1)(r_2-z^*)}dz$ where $\Gamma= \{ z: |z|=r \}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

**Problem:**: $\int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{z^2+z^{-2}}{(z^*-r_1)(r_2-z^*)}dz$ where $\Gamma= \{ z: |z|=r \}$ ($r_2>r>r_1>0$).

**Question:** How to solve this integral?

**My attempt:** My first idea is to use residue theorem but this function is not holomorphic (so I can not use residue theorem). If I try to simplify this integral i get:
$$ \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{z^4+1}{z^2(z^*-r_1)(r_2-z^*)}dz $$
but I can not get anything useful from this (as far as I can see).
I tried to parametrize this integral with $z=re^{i\theta}$ and I get:
$$\dfrac{i}{r} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{(r^4e^{4i\theta}+1)e^{i\theta} d\theta }{e^{2i\theta}(re^{-i\theta}-r_1)(r_2-re^{-i\theta})} $$
and this is not useful (as far as I can see). I have no idea how to proceed to solve the problem.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: first replace $z^{*} by \frac {r^{2}} z$ (on $\Gamma$, $zz^{*}=r^{2}$).  Once you do this the given function takes a new form which  has poles at $r^{2} /r_1$ and $r^{2}/r_2$. Find the residue at these points and apply Residue Theorem.

Comment: Is the function from the problem holomorhpic anywhere in the complex plane? If not then how can residue theorem be applied when meromorphic functions must be holomorphic on domain exepct for discrete set of isoleted poles. If yes how come when it has $z^*$?

Comment: You have to first replace $z^{*}$ by $\frac {r^{2}} z$. You can do this without changing the value of the integral . After doing this you will get a function which is analytic except for two poles.